# How to check if a primal optimisation problem is feasible and bounded?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Consider the following Primal LP

$$
\min_{x_1,x_2,x_3} x_1+x_2+x_3 $$
subject to constraints,
$$
x_1+x_2 \ge a \\
x_1+x_3 \ge b \\
x_2+x_3 \ge c\\
x_1 \ge d \\
x_2 \ge e \\
x_3 \ge f 
$$

Here $$a,b,c,d,e,f \quad \text{are constants} $$
There is no restrcition on variables $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ (free variables). How do I establish that this primal problem is feasible and bounded? Could someone please help?

Also, in general, how does one establish an optimisation problem is feasible and bounded?

Answer (score 1):

Can check if LP is bounded by seeing if primal has a feasible solution and dual has a feasible solution, then primal is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular problem,

We have $x_1+x_2+x_3 \ge a + f$. Hence it must be bounded and can't to go $-\infty$.

To construct a feasible solution, we just need the variables to be large enough to be feasible. $(|a|+|b|+|d|, |a|+|c|+|e|, |b|+|c|+|f|)$ is a feasible solution.

For general linear programming problem, we know how to solve it, we can convert it to a standard form and use simplex algorithm.

Theoretically, for linear programming problem, we can also use duality theorem and shows that the primal and dual share the same objective value.

Answer (score 0):

Add the first 3 inequalities, then add the last 3 ones : you get

$$x_1+x_2+x_3 \ge M \ \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \ \ M:=\max((a+b+c)/2,d+e+f)$$

Therefore, taking all $x_k$ equal to $M$ gives a feasible solution to  the primal problem.